# Intersections between two lists of thousands of networks

Tags: python, networking, apache-pig

I have a huge list of networks (called A) and I need to check if the addresses of these networks are present in another network list (called B) :

The format of the two lists is the following:

Liste A

```
1.2.3.4
145.2.3.0/24
6.5.0.0/16
3.4.1.0/24
```

Liste B

```
1.5.6.7
10.0.3.0/24
1.2.3.0/24
3.4.0.0/16
```

Expected result of the intersection of two lists A ∩ B: etc

```
1.2.3.4
3.4.1.0/24
```

My first test was naively:

- List all ips with [ipaddr](https://code.google.com/p/ipaddr-py/source/browse/#git/branches/3144) module
- Put the IPs for each list in two [set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Set)
- do to the [intersection](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) of the two set.

This method works with small lists. However, this solution is not suitable with thousands of networks (ie several million IP addresses) because I [don't have enough memory](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.MemoryError). Moreover, this solution is not suitable with **IPv6** networks.

**What is the most effective way to do the intersection of the two lists?**

Addition: I have also to repeat this between list A and other lists as B : A ∩ C, A ∩ D, etc.

I'm open to all suggestions, even with [pig](http://pig.apache.org/index.html) :-)

**Solution :**

```py
def chunks(l, n):
  for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
    yield l[i:i+n]

res = []
for chunk_a in chunks(A, 1000):
  for chunk_b in chunks(B, 1000):
      C = IPSet(chunk_a) & IPSet(chunk_b)
      if C > IPSet([]):
          res.append(C)
```

Comment: `3.4.0.0/16` is in both lists, so shouldn't that be in the intersection instead of `3.4.1.0/24`?

Comment: You can represent an IP4 address by 6 bytes, 4bytes for the address, 2bytes for the port. So 5 million addresses use about 29Mbytes memory, if you use numpy array to save the addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possibility based on the `netaddr` package which implements IP address/network sets.

Firstly, consider that if A = A1 ∪ A2 and B = B1 ∪ B2, then A ∩ B = (A1 ∩ B1) ∪ (A1 ∩ B2) ∪ (A2 ∩ B1) ∪ (A2 ∩ B2).

So you break up your lists into small sets and use the above to calculate the intersection incrementally. For instance:

```
from netaddr import IPSet

A1 = IPSet(['1.2.3.4','145.2.3.0/24'])
A2 = IPSet(['6.5.0.0/16','3.4.1.0/24'])
B1 = IPSet(['1.5.6.7','10.0.3.0/24'])
B2 = IPSet(['1.2.3.0/24','3.4.0.0/16'])

A1B1 = A1 & B1
A1B2 = A1 & B2
A2B1 = A2 & B1
A2B2 = A2 & B2

A1B1 | A1B2 | A2B1 | A2B2
-> IPSet(['1.2.3.4/32', '3.4.1.0/24'])
```

But considering that, when using IPSet, you won't need to list out all the addresses, you may be able to perform the intersection without resorting to breaking up the list into small sets.

---

Update: intersection of two lists of 5,000 randomly defined networks (length 8 to 24 bits) takes only a couple of seconds on a laptop with 4GB of memory:

Make the two lists of IP addresses:

```
import random

f = open('iplist1.txt','w')
for i in range(5000):
    ip = '.'.join([str(random.randint(1,254)) for i in range(4)])
    ip += '/'+str(random.randint(8,24))
    f.write(ip+'\n')
f.close()

f = open('iplist2.txt','w')
for i in range(5000):
    ip = '.'.join([str(random.randint(1,254)) for i in range(4)])
    ip += '/'+str(random.randint(8,24))
    f.write(ip+'\n')
f.close()
```

Intersect them:

```
import time
import netaddr

ipset1 = netaddr.IPSet(open('iplist1.txt','r').readlines())
ipset2 = netaddr.IPSet(open('iplist2.txt','r').readlines())

print "Set 1:", len(ipset1), "IP addresses"
print "Set 2:", len(ipset2), "IP addresses"

start = time.time()
ipset = ipset1 & ipset2
print "Elapsed:", time.time() - start
print "Intersection:",len(ipset),"IP addresses"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're open to Pig, then nothing could be easier.  It will have no troubles with running out of memory, and intersections are simple with `JOIN`:

```
A = LOAD '/path/to/A' AS (ip:chararray);
B = LOAD '/path/to/B' AS (ip:chararray);

intersection = FOREACH (JOIN A BY ip, B BY ip) GENERATE A::ip;
STORE intersection INTO '/path/to/output';
```

Done.

Comment: This solution works fine with IP adresses. But this solution doesn't handle the  cidr notatation, isn't it ? Before, I must enumerate all IP of the network (2^64 IP at least in IPv6...)

Comment: Why would that be any different?  It's just comparing strings.  If you had an IP address of `asegaegas11351.13511###` it wouldn't complain. There's no enumeration involved here, just the intersection of two arbitrary lists of objects.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I still don't understand. Example with two lists of just 1 item: : "10.1.2.3" and "10.0.0.0/16". The expected result of the intersection is 10.1.2.3. For me, the "simple" comparison of the two strings don't return the real intersection due to CIDR notation. Can you elaborate? I'm really interested to understand your solution.

Comment: I misunderstood what you meant by "intersection". (In fact, I'm still not quite sure.)  I suspect there would be a way to do this in Pig using a UDF, but I'd need to understand your needs better.  I'm not well-versed in IP address semantics.

Comment: Because comment is not a good place to explain, see more explanation at http://piratepad.net/4YTmIm2bDS

Comment: Thank you for enlightening me.  This is an interesting problem.  It may or may not be efficiently solvable by Pig, I will have to think about it a while.  Maybe this will help you in finding a solution in whatever language -- this is not any arbitrary intersection.  You are purely looking for sets in A (e.g., 145.2.3.0/24 is a set of addresses) that are subsets of sets in B, and vice versa.  I'll keep thinking about this and post back if I come up with something.